# Oracle Bind Variables in Mybatis

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, mybatis, ojdbc

I'm currently facing a problem concerning an Oracle Bind Variables usage in Mybatis. I have a very simple update query which looks as follows:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET VARCHAR_COL = #{value1},
TIMESTAMP_COL = #{value2}
WHERE id = #{id}
```

The thing that is getting wrong with this simple query is that my DBA started (rightly) complaining about very high factor of Hard Parse Calls for this statement. It seems like nearly all executions are getting hard parsed.

I know, that to avoid hard parsing one should use Oracle Bind Variables to let Oracle DBMS create plan once and then just replace variables for every call. And, as far as I know, Mybatis is using JDBC Prepared Statement to create database query, and, according to MyBatis manual, parameters placed at #{} (starting # instead of $) are passed as JDBC Parameters. Going deeper, I got an information that JDBC Parameters used in Prepared Statement have a native support for Bind Variables. Everything looks fine, however something is not, as Oracle is always hard parsing. Did I misunderstood some concepts or just something I wrote above is not true?

I know I can workaround this case using Oracle Stored Procedure, which always use Bind Variables for statements called inside it, but I'm looking for a full understanding and a cleaner fix.

My version of MyBatis is 3.3.0, and I'm using ojdbc7 version 12.1.0.1.0. Additionally, I noticed that an insert statement as simple as below is causing the same problem with mybatis 3.4.6, ojdbc7 version 12.1.0.2.0:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE
(
COL1,
COL2,
COL3,
COL4,
COL5,
COL6,
COL7,
COL8,
COL9,
COL10
)
VALUES
(
#{fv.val1, jdbcType=NUMERIC},
#{fv.val2, jdbcType=NUMERIC},
#{fv.val3, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
#{fv.val4, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
#{fv.val5, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
#{fv.val6, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
#{fv.val7, jdbcType=TIMESTAMP},
#{fv.val8, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
#{fv.val9, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
#{fv.val10, jdbcType=NUMERIC}
)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: MyBatis uses `PreparedStatement` unless you specify `statementType` explicitly. You should execute the same `PreparedStatement` using a plain old JDBC app (i.e. no-MyBatis) and see if the hard-parse occurs or not.